# Using Parameters as Column Values in a FULLTEXT Query

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Is it possible to pass in column names as parameters in a SQLServer 2008 contains fulltext query?

This does not appear to be possible:

```
DECLARE @MYCOLS AS NVARCHAR(30);
DECLARE @MYVALUE AS NVARCHAR(100);
SET @MYCOLS = 'NOTES,TITLE'
SET @MYVALUE = 'Chicago'

SELECT NOTES FROM MY_NOTE_TABLE WHERE FULLTEXT((@MYCOLS),@MYVALUE)
```

where MY_NOTE_TABLE has the columns ID (IDENTITY), TITLE NVARCHAR(100), NOTES NVARCHAR(MAX).

Works just fine if the columns are specifically named, but I'd really like to use a parameter if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your in a Procedure or SSRS, something like this...

```
BEGIN 

 DECLARE @SQLSTR VARCHAR(100)
 DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(50)

 SET @Columns = 'FirstName, LastName'
 SET @SQLSTR = 'Select ' + @Columns +' FROM EM WHERE Status=$A$'
 SET @SQLSTR = REPLACE(@SQLSTR, '$', CHAR(39)) 

 Execute (@SQLSTR)

END
```

I include the $'s and CHAR(39) replace as an easy way to fix up the statements 'quoted' text, there are other ways too...

In the end, your just executing a string, you've pieced together...

Comment: I am familiar with this technique. It is in fact what I'm doing. But in the fulltext clause, doing this results in a syntax error.